# jQuery trigger click (or select) on chosen dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to trigger a click function on page load with jQuery on chosen's dropdown option so that the follow-up action can take place but haven't been able to get it work.

I've tried:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("customlist_chzn_o_2").trigger('click');
},10);
```

or

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {   
    jQuery('#customlist').val(9).trigger("chosen:updated")  
});
```

or

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {   
    jQuery('#customlist_chzn_o_2').trigger("chosen:updated")    
});
```

None of them are working, please note that my select's id is `#customlist` the id of dropdown element in chosen which I need to click is `#customlist_chzn_o_2` and the value of the select option is ***9***

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Can you show us your full code?

Comment: This code will be applied to virtuemart's custom fields area in admin's add product view.

Comment: It doesn't matter **where**. If I understand you correctly, you are using a plugin for the **custom** dropdown. Don't you? If so, tell us which. It will be better if you can create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: The plugin being used on which I need to work the code on is Chosen based on jQuery, here it is: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to trigger the `change` event on the original `select`, not on the custom or his `option`s.

> When working with form fields, you often want to perform some behavior after a value has been selected or deselected. Whenever a user selects a field in Chosen, it triggers a "change" event on the original form field

But when **you** change the original `select` value, **than** you should trigger `chosen:updated`.

> If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.

<sup>https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events</sup>

```js
var sel1 = $('#sel1').chosen({width: '150px'}).change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});

sel1.trigger('change');

var sel2 = $('#custom_field').chosen({width: '150px'});

//$('button').click(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
  sel2.val('9');
  
  // Than you should trigger the "chosen:updated"
  sel2.trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="sel1">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<select id="custom_field">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>9</option>
</select>

<button>Set custom_field's value to "9"</button>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't work: 
`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#custom_field').val('9');
  jQuery('#custom_field').trigger('chosen:updated');
 });`
I'll try to test that code with button click instead of document ready. 
PS: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I was updated my answer. Is your code similar to this? I changed the names and the event just like yours.

Comment: It did trigger it but the follow up script is giving conflict. I'll have to sort that out myself. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: `giving conflict` what do you mean? Also, if you find my answer helpfully for other users, please accept it.

Comment: I think I need to trigger a click event rather than choosing the value by default.

Comment: If you want only to change the value, I recommend to use `change` and all of that. Because, if you will add a `change` listener (in the future) it will not brake your logic. But it's up to you, of course.

Answer (score 1):

To actually "trigger" the click event as if it was made by a user, I had to combine multiple answers as follows:

```
        $('#sel1')[0].selectedIndex = 0; // make selection
        $('#sel1')[0].focus(); // set the focus
        $('#sel1').trigger('change'); // actually trigger click event for listeners
```

Answer (score 0):

`chosen` doesn't have a direct trigger for click/select. We have to take the underlying `select` element's selected value and explicitly run the contents of chosen's `.on('change',..)` .

```
// Original trigger function thru chosen.js
$('#custSelect').on('change', function(evt,params) {
    var custID = params.selected;
    //that gives us the VALUE of the selected option

    // below are the executive actions being done
    if(custID) chooseOne(custID);
});

// Programmatically changing the selected option
var e = document.getElementById('custSelect');
e.selectedIndex +=1 ; // selecting next option in the dropdown list

$('#custSelect').trigger('chosen:updated'); // this is only COSMETIC.
// updates the view to match underlying select element 
// but doesn't trigger chosen's on-change event

// now we retrieve the newly selected option's value:
var custID = e[e.selectedIndex].value; // analogous to params.selected above
// ...and do the execution ourselves.
if(custID) chooseOne(custID);
```

Alternatively, don't rely on chosen's on-change at all, and make one for the original `<select>` html element instead. I won't go into that here.